# ASP.Net pages don't load on IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I'm doing application testing on Windows Server 2012  to check compatibility of our web apps (in .Net 4) and am having issues loading any ASPX page. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling all of the .Net, IIS and ASP.Net roles from Server Manager numerous times. I also found that `aspnet_regiis` no longer works in Server 2012, it just gives a message to use the role/feature pages instead. I'm at a loss, has anyone else tried IIS 8 yet?

I get the following message:

```
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Most likely causes:
•It is possible that a handler mapping is missing. By default, the static file handler processes all content.
•The feature you are trying to use may not be installed.
•The appropriate MIME map is not enabled for the Web site or application. (Warning: Do not create a MIME map for content that users should not download, such as .ASPX pages or .config files.)
•If ASP.NET is not installed.

Things you can try:
•In system.webServer/handlers: ◦Ensure that the expected handler for the current page is mapped.
    ◦Pay extra attention to preconditions (for example, runtimeVersion, pipelineMode, bitness) and compare them to the settings for your application pool.
    ◦Pay extra attention to typographical errors in the expected handler line.

•Please verify that the feature you are trying to use is installed.
• Verify that the MIME map is enabled or add the MIME map for the Web site using the command-line tool appcmd.exe. 
    1.To set a MIME type, use the following syntax: %SystemRoot%\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='string',mimeType='string']
    2.The variable fileExtension string is the file name extension and the variable mimeType string is the file type description.
    3.For example, to add a MIME map for a file which has the extension ".xyz": appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.xyz',mimeType='text/plain']
    Warning: Ensure that this MIME mapping is needed for your Web server before adding it to the list. Configuration files such as .CONFIG or dynamic scripting pages such as .ASP or .ASPX, should not be downloaded directly and should always be processed through a handler. Other files such as database files or those used to store configuration, like .XML or .MDF, are sometimes used to store configuration information. Determine if clients can download these file types before enabling them. 
 •Install ASP.NET.
 •Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here. 

 Detailed Error Information:

 Module
    StaticFileModule 

 Notification
    ExecuteRequestHandler 

 Handler
    StaticFile 

 Error Code
    0x80070032 

 Requested URL
    http://localhost:80/login.aspx 

 Physical Path
    C:\Inetpub\WEBSITE\login.aspx 

 Logon Method
    Anonymous 

 Logon User
    Anonymous
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after fighting this issue for the last few days I reset the VM to the base snapshot that I took immediately after finishing the OS install. I followed the exact same steps that I documented during my first runthrough to install the IIS and App Development features then installed my apps and now it works. I have no idea why or how it worked this time where it didn't before, but at least it is working now.